# Genitiv vs Satzkonstruktion mit von

Tags: genitive, possessive

Es ist mir noch immer nicht klar, wann man den Genitiv verwenden muss und wann man auch einen Satz mit *von* und Dativ bilden kann.

Auf Niederländisch (meiner Muttersprache) gibt es so etwas wie den Genitiv nicht. Wir machen einfach immer Satzkonstruktionen mit *von*. Aber ich habe schon gemerkt, dass auf Deutsch manchmal beides möglich ist und dass manchmal nur die Verwendung des Genitiv richtig ist. Gibt es hierzu klare Regeln?

Zum Beispiel:

> - Der Vater meines Vaters ist mein Opa
> - Der Vater von meinem Vater ist mein Opa.

In diesem Fall sind beide richtig.

> - Die Schüler der Klasse 12
> - Die Schüler von Klasse 12.

Soweit ich weiß, ist in diesem Fall nur der erste Satz richtig.

Comment: Sadly, proper use of Genetiv is dying out, at least in spoken language. "Wegen des Wetters", dammit!

Comment: @Raphael: Actually, this is not quite right. Concerning prepositions, the language is shifting between both cases. „Trotz des Wetters“ has been Dativ 100 years back.

Comment: Die Bewertung der beiden Beispiele ist genau falsch herum. "Die Schüler von der Klasse 12" wäre Umgangssprache, aber "Die Schüler von Klasse 12" ist genauso korrekt wie "Die Schüler der Klasse 12" und manchmal stilistisch vorzuziehen. "Der Vater von meinem Opa" ist Umgangssprache, aber vielleicht nicht ganz so ungepflegt wie "Die Schüler von der Klasse 12".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In der geschriebenen Sprache ist der besitzanzeigende Genitiv stets der Konstruktion `von` + `Dativ` vorzuziehen, da Letzteres als schlechter Stil angesehen wird. [(1)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#Possessiv-Konstruktionen) In der gesprochenen Sprache hingegen wird die Dativ-Konstruktion mit `von` häufiger verwendet als der eigentlich korrekte Genitiv. So wird man folgende oder ähnliche Sätze oft hören:

> Hast du schon die neue Melodie von der Tagesschau gehört?
>
> Ich kenne die Nummer vom Pizza-Lieferservice nicht.

Manche Menschen würden die folgenden korrekten Sätze – gesprochen – wohl sogar als hochgestochen empfinden:

> Hast du schon die neue Melodie der Tagesschau gehört?
>
> Ich kenne die Nummer des Pizza-Lieferservices nicht.

Darüber hinaus gibt es Präpositionen, die den Genitiv unbedingt erforderlich machen, aber auch unter der Ersetzung durch den Dativ leiden. Die bekannteste darunter ist wahrscheinlich `wegen`. Korrekt muss es z. B. heißen:

> Wegen schlechten Wetters mussten wir unsere Wanderung absagen.

Einen amüsanten und auch sehr informativen Artikel zu diesem Thema gibt es auf [Spiegel online](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-der-dativ-ist-dem-genitiv-sein-tod-a-267725.html).

Was dein Beispiel mit der Klasse 12 angeht, so lautet die Konstruktion mit Dativ eigentlich:

> Die Schüler von der Klasse 12.

Und ist genauso unschön, wenngleich gebräuchlich wie die anderen Beispiele. Präpositionen sind in vielen Sprachen eine schwierige Sache und meist gibt es keine Regeln dafür. Hier würde ich auch folgende Präpositionen ohne Artikel (aber mit Dativ) gelten lassen:

> Die Schüler von Klasse 12.
>
> Die Schüler aus Klasse 12.
>
> Die Schüler in Klasse 12.

Hier können wegen des fehlenden Artikels sowohl die Schüler einer bestimmten Klasse als auch alle Schüler in der 12. Klassenstufe in ganz Deutschland (oder woanders) gemeint sein.

Comment: In my experience, laziness is the main driver here. So I'd expect "der Tagesschau", not "von der Tagessschau". Definitely "vom Pizzaservice", though -- sadly. (By the way, why the Deppenbindestrich? ;))

Comment: @Raphael Concerning `von` vs `von der`: this probably varies from region to region. Where I come from (south-west) you will hear `von der` much more frequently.