# Wann benutzt man »Dem ... seine ...«

Tags: grammaticality, possessive

Auf einer bekannten Seite, auf der man Lyrics zu Songs aufschreiben und veröffentlichen kann, habe ich eine Anmerkung verfasst welche den folgenden Satz beinhaltet, jedoch wurde mir dieser Satz von einem anderen User korrigiert.

> Der Autor befand sich in einer Selbstfindungsphase oder Früh-Life Krise: Dem Autor seine Realität wurde...

*Dem Autor seine Realität* wurde gelöscht und daraus entstand nur ein *Seine Realität.* Benützt man *Dem Autor seine* hier nicht, weil *Autor* schon im vorherigen Satz betont wurde? Oder ist *Dem Autor seine* schlichtweg grammatikalisch falsch?

Comment: Ähnliche Frage, aber kein Duplikat: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6081/118

Comment: Wie geht denn der Satz weiter? Ich kann mir zwei Möglichkeiten
vorstellen, warum der Satz problematisch ist:
(1) "Dem Autor seine Realität" wurde als Ersatz für
"Die Realität des Autors" verwendet. Das ist *sehr* umgangssprachlich.
(2) Die Satzstellung ist falsch,
es muß "Seine Realität wurde dem Autor ..." heißen.
Beides ist möglich, aber um beurteilen zu können, was zutrifft,
muß man den Rest des Satzes kennen, insbesondere das Verb.

Comment: Die elaborierteste Variante, die ich je gehört habe, wäre, auf das Beispiel der Frage gemünzt: »Der Autor dem seine Realität …« Ursprünglich gehört als »der Bechtoldsheimer dem sei Fleischwurst« in Rheinhessen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Der Dialekt jener Region in der ich aufgewachsen bin (Graz; Eltern aus der Oststeiermark), enthält keinen Genitiv, und das trifft auf viele Dialekte anderer Regionen ebenfalls zu. (Ich weiß leider nicht, wie weit verbreitet genitivlose Dialekte im deutschen Sprachraum sind.)

Trotzdem braucht man auch in diesen Dialekten eine Möglichkeit, Besitzverhältnisse sprachlich auszudrücken. Und zumindest in jenen genitivlosen Varianten der deutschen Sprache die ich kenne, wird das wie folgt gemacht:

Der Besitzer wird im Dativ verwendet, und mit einem Possesivpronomen mit der besessenen Sache verbunden:

> **Meinem Vater sein Auto** ist rot.
>   Standard 1: **Meines Vaters Auto** ist rot.
>   Std 2: **Das Auto meines Vaters** ist rot.
>
> **Dem Kalb sein Fell** glänzt.
>   Std 1: **Des Kalbs Fell** glänzt.
>   Std 2: **Das Fell des Kalbes** glänzt.
>
> **Der Schwester ihr Kleid** hat Falten.
>   Std 1: **Der Schwester Kleid** hat Falten.
>   Std 2: **Das Kleid der Schwester** hat Falten.

Der Vollständigkeit halber möchte ich anmerken, dass natürlich im Dialekt andere Vokabel verwendet werden. Z.B. erstes Beispiel, wie man es in der Oststeiermark tatsächlich verwenden würde:

> Mein Foda sei Auto is rot.

Das waren jetzt Beispiele in denen der Genitiv als Teil einer Nominalgruppe auftritt, die wiederum das Subjekt des Satzes ist.

Aber es geht auch anders:

> Ich sehe **dem Vater sein Auto**.
>   Std 1: Ich sehe **meines Vaters Auto**.
>   Std 2: Ich sehe **das Auto meines Vaters**.
>
> Das Kleid gehört **dem Lehrer seiner Schwester**.
>   Std 1: Das Kleid gehört **des Lehrers Schwester**.
>   Std 2: Das Kleid gehört **der Schwester des Lehrers**.

Und natürlich darf [dieses berühmte Beispiel](https://www.amazon.de/Dativ-ist-dem-Genitiv-sein/dp/3462034480) nicht fehlen (Hier erscheinen die Besitzverhältnisse innerhalb eines Gleichsetzungsnominativ):

> Der Dativ ist **dem Genitiv sein Tod**.
>   Std 1: Der Dativ ist **des Genitivs Tod**.
>   Std 2: Der Dativ ist **der Tod des Genitivs**.

Wie hinlänglich bekannt gibt es zwei Arten den Genitiv zu bilden, und die Variante, die in der Standardsprache deutlich häufiger verwendet wird ist jene, die ich als »Std 2« bezeichnet habe. Man sieht aber auch, das die Dativ-Version eher mit der seltener verwendeten Standard-Version (die ich mit »Std 1« bezeichnet habe) verwandt ist.

---

Kommen wird zu dem Satz aus der Frage:

> **Dem Autor seine Realität** ist verzerrt.

Hier tritt der Autor innerhalb jener Nominalgruppe auf, die des Satzes Subjekt ist. Daher muss er auch in der standarddeutschen Version irgendwo im Subjekt auftreten, und das geht nur im Genitiv, wofür es zwei Möglichkeiten gibt:

> a) **Des Autors Realität** ist verzerrt.
>   b) **Die Realität des Autors** ist verzerrt.

Wenn der Autor aber schon in einem vorausgehendem Satz genannt wurde, also schon im Kontext existiert, kann man auf ihn durch ein maskulines Possessivpronomen der 3. Person Singular, also »sein« verweisen:

> (Der **Autor** wird erwähnt.) **Seine** Realität ist verzerrt.

Diese Konstruktion hat aber nichts mit dem oben beschriebenen besitzanzeigenden Dativ zu tun.

---

**Addendum:**

Deutsch ist eine plurizentrische Sprache, das heißt, dass es kein einheitliches Deutsch gibt. Es gab auch in der Vergangenheit noch nie ein einheitliches Deutsch.

Deutsch war und ist in Wahrheit ein Kontinuum aus fast ebensovielen Dialekten wie es Sprecher gibt. (Das ist natürlich übertrieben, kommt der Sache aber trotzdem näher als zu behaupten alle Deutschsprechenden würden genau dieselbe Sprache sprechen). Von einem Kontinuum spricht man deswegen, weil sich geographisch nahe beieinander lebende Menschen sehr gut miteinander verständigen können, während z.B. Menschen aus benachbarten Alpentälern manchmal schon Probleme haben, einander zu verstehen.

Daher gibt es schon seit Jahrhunderten immer wieder Versuche, ein einheitliches Deutsch zu schaffen, doch will ich hier nicht alle derartigen Unternehmungen aufzählen. Der bei weitem erfolgreichste Versuch ist ein unabsichtlicher Versuch, und er läuft gerade jetzt: Es handelt sich um Kabel- und Satelitenfernsehen in Kombination mit ausgebildeten Sprechern (Schauspieler und Nachrichtensprecher), die ein einheitliches Deutsch über den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum (Deutschland, Österreich, Schweiz und angrenzende deutschsprachige Gebiete) verteilen.

Aber dieser Versuch ist noch lange nicht zu Ende. Es wird noch zwei oder drei Generationen dauern, bis die Menschen zuhause, am Arbeitsplatz und abends in der Kneipe wirklich so sprechen, wie sie es in den Medien hören. Und solange das nicht der Fall ist, wird es weiterhin sowohl im Wortschatz als auch in der Grammatik zum Teil erhebliche Abweichungen geben, und auch die Standardsprache wird sich noch weiter verändern.

Comment: Sehr interessant! Interessant ist auch das Missverständnis, welches aufgrund von "Das Kleid gehört dem Lehrer seiner Schwester" möglich wird :D

Comment: @Ludi: Das Missverständnis entsteht nur bei jenen, die mit dieser Grammatik nicht vertraut sind. Ich bin damit aber aufgewachsen und habe eher ein anderes Problem: Bei Sätzen wie »Der Schwester Kleid hat Falten.« protestiert meine interne Grammar-Engine jedesmal ganz heftig und will ein »ihr« zwischen der »Schwester« und dem »Kleid« eingefügt haben, was natürlich nicht den Standard-Regeln (aber sehr wohl den Regeln meines Muttersprachendialekts) entspricht.

Comment: Man sollte vielleicht anmerken, dass man Standard 1 nicht verwenden kann, ohne altertümelnd zu wirken. Bei Poeten mag das okay sein, für die Allgemeinsprache aber nur eingeschränkt. | Dieses einheitliche Deutsch konnte aber nur überall verteilt werden, weil es jemand vor einem halben Jahrtausend einheitlich gemacht hat. | Ansonsten sehr gute Antwort.

Comment: @deponensvogel: »weil es jemand vor einem halben Jahrtausend einheitlich gemacht hat.« Das ist ihm aber nicht vollständig gelungen. In Österreich und der Schweiz wird auch gegenwärtig noch ein anderes Deutsch an Schulen gelehrt und in die Gesetzestexte geschrieben als in Deutschland. Derzeit gibt es drei voneinander abweichende Standards, und das wird noch mindestens ein paar Jahrzehnte lang so bleiben.

Comment: Die Abweichungen zwischen Österreichischem und Bundesdeutsch (die Standarsprachen!) sind so minimal, dass man sie vernachlässigen kann. Bei den Eidgenossen ist das anders, aber die haben ja schon immer ihre eigenen Brötchen gebacken. | Der gute Herr Luther war da aber nicht der einzige. Die Arbeit der Wiener und Prager Kanzleien darf man nicht unterschätzen.

Comment: @deponensvogel: Die Bücher über diesen »vernachlässigbaren« Unterschied nehmen aber allein in meiner privaten Bibliothek knapp einen halben Laufmeter Platz weg, wobei sich zugegebenermaßen die meisten mit dem Vokabular befassen. Aber es gibt auch Unterschiede in der Grammatik. So heißt z.B. jene Zeitform, die im deutschen Deutsch »vollendete Gegenwart« genannt wird (das Perfekt) im österreichischen Deutsch (z.B. im Schulunterricht) ganz schlicht »Vergangenheit«, und wird auch tatsächlich verwendet um Vergangenes zu beschreiben, egal ob sie abgeschlossen sind oder nicht.

Comment: Das Perfekt wird überall einzig und allein dafür verwendet, um Vergangenes zu beschreiben. Wir haben Perfekt und Präteritum im Deutschen, nicht Perfekt und Imperfekt. Wer das Perfekt als vollendete Gegenwart verwendet, der erliegt einem Fehler im Verstand und hat sich zu lange mit romanischen Sprachen oder dem Englischen befasst. | Der Unterschied im Wortschatz ist innerhalb der Bundesrepublik größer als zwischen Österreich und seinem Bruder in Kultur und Sprache, dem Freistaat Bayern.

Comment: Ergänzung zum Perfekt: Im Deutschen ist die Aufteilung der grammatischen Zeitformen ganz klar. Man macht es den Deutschlernenden nur unnötig schwerer, als es ist. Präteritum und Perfekt können austauschbar beide verwendet werden, um Vergangenes auszudrücken. In der Schönliteratur ist allein das Präteritum zulässig, in der Allgemeinsprache darf man mischen, wie man lustig ist. Wobei einem auffallen wird, dass je südlicher man geht, das Präteritum immer weniger wird, bis es gänzlich verschwindet.

Answer (score 3):

Im "Schriftdeutschen" gibt es dieses Konstrukt nicht. Herr Schölnast hat schon sehr gut erläutert, dass diese Form des "Ersatzgenitivs" in vielen Dialekten die einzige Möglichkeit darstellt, auszudrücken, was man in "Schriftdeutschen" mit dem Genitiv ausdrückt. Man sagt also in diversen Dialekten "Dem Fischer sein Kind", statt:

> Des Fischers Kind.
>   Das Kind des Fischers.

Nun gibt es aber einige Gründe, warum man bei einer der beiden Sprachvarianten bleiben sollte - d.h. Dialekt, wenn man ihn spricht auch konsequent sprechen sollte. Diese Konstruktion erzeugt nämlich Sätze, die im "Schriftdeutschen" eine ganz andere Bedeutung haben. Ich nutze mal den Satz von Herrn Schölnast:

> Das Kleid gehört dem Lehrer seiner Schwester.

Im "Schriftdeutschen" interpretiert man das so, dass der Lehrer (der jemandes Schwester unterrichtet) Kleider besitzt! Man stellt sich dann wahrscheinlich vor, wie Oberstudienrat von Stein in Frauenkleidern herumläuft. Auch wenn das nicht zwingend folgt.  ;-)

Betrachten wir noch ein weiteres Beispiel dafür, wie wichtig es ist, diese beiden Konventionen nicht zu mischen:

> Ich habe dem Manfred sein Auto gekauft.

bedeutet im “Schriftdeutschen”, dass der Sprecher, vermutlich Manfreds Vater, diesem ein Auto gekauft hat. Im Dialekt bedeutet es dagegen, dass der Sprecher der Käufer eben jenes Autos ist!

Es gibt noch andere interessante Fälle:

> Dem Volk sein Recht.

Bei diesem Satz, denke ich intuitiv an:

> Gebt dem Volk sein Recht!

Erst wenn die dialektale Umgebung passt, verstehe ich ihn richtig!

Aus diesen Überlegungen heraus, versteht man teils, warum so ein Satz korrigiert wird, wenn auch im von Ihnen genannten Falle keine Möglichkeiten der Missinterpretation erkennbar sind.

Answer (score 2):

"Dem seine" ist im Dialekt (z.B. Kölsch), im Hochdeutschen wird der Genitiv mit "seine" oder "dessen" gebildet.

Statt

> Dem Hans seine Hose

benutzt man

> Hans' Hose

Oder, frei nach Konrad Beikircher:

> Dem Hans seine Hose ihre Gürtel sein Schnall

oder auf Hochdeutsch

> Hans' Gürtelschnalle

Comment: Ich würde nicht sagen, dass es "Dialekt" oder mundartlich sei, sondern umgangssprachlich und zwar in großen Teilen vom deutschspraclichem Raum

Comment: In ganz Österreich sind »dem (Mann/Kind) sein« und »der (Frau) ihr« gängig.